# SQL Query: Selecting a person who is a member of all existing groups

Tags: relational-theory

I'm tinkering around with my very first SQL queries and am completely baffled by a problem I encountered.

Let's say I have the following database:

```
PERSON(PID, Name)
MEMBER(PID, GroupID)
```

How would I go about creating an SQL query that selects only the tuples of the persons who are a member of all existing groups (i.e. GroupIDs)?

I tripped over everything I could find regarding IN, EXISTS, ALL and the likes without finding an elegant solution.

Thank you very much,

Pety

Comment: Look for "Relational Division".

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get to this answer.  I'll tackle it in two parts.  The first is to find out how many groups there are.  This is a simple summary query:

```
select count(distinct GroupID)
from MEMBER
```

The second is how many groups one person is in.  This is similar:

```
select
  PID,
  COUNT(*)
from MEMBER
group by PID
```

Next you want to tie these together

```
select
  PID,
  COUNT(*)
from MEMBER
group by PID
having COUNT(*) = (select count(distinct GroupID)
                   from MEMBER)
```

Depending on which RDBMS you're using (Oracle, DB2, MySQL) there may be other syntaxes or layouts which make this faster, prettier or otherwise more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the total number of groups, you could try:

```
SELECT PID, COUNT(GROUPID) FROM MEMBERS GROUP BY PID;
```

Then limit the results by the number of groups.

Comment: That will tell you how many groups each PID is in but will not say which PIDs are in *all* groups, as was asked.